# Mie's scattering Theory Problem

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, scattering

Is Mie's theory which describes the scattering of EM wave off sphere , possible to extend to spheroidal ? object or arbitrary shape with finite series expression ? 
I tried to replace the radial vector of the mie's theory by a general normal vector. And I got 6 equations out of it, rather than the standard 4 equations you got by matching Boundary conditions. And there is a problem with the scattering and internal field. My professor says the change of geometry would also change the scattering field equations, but is it actually non-analytical to write in spherical coordinate? I know it's analytical in T matrix or Spheroidal coordinate. But I hope to create some new theory.

Note that my incident field is plane wave, [image]
[image]
[image]
Apart from the standard sphere's solution, which are these 4 below..

[image]

I also got these two.
[image]

Am i doing anything stupid ? Hope anyone can shed a light on this problem.

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mie_scattering

Comment: Maybe you have seen this but there is a Mie theory extension to a spheroidal particle, look up "Light scattering by a spheroidal particle S Asano, G Yamamoto - Applied optics, 1975"